# Annotation processing unknown Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, java-8, preprocessor

currently I am writing an Annotation processor, which will generate new source code. This Processor is isolated from the application itself, as it is a step in building the project and I seperated the whole buildsystem from the application.

This is where the problem starts, because I want to process an Annotation that is created in the application. Let's name it **CustomAnnotation**. with the fully qualified name **com.company.api.annotation.CustomAnnotation**.

In the processor I can search for annotations by the fully qualified name, what's really nice. Now I seem to be able to get the Methods, field etc that are annotated since I can call the function **getElementsAnnotatedWith** with **TypeElement** instead of **Class**.

Now our CustomAnnotation has fields and variables in it and normally I would get the Annotation itself like this: `Class annotation = Element.getAnnotation(Class)` But I can't use this since CustomAnnotation is not available as Class Object.(sure, it's not known to the processor) I tried using TypeMirror and other available things but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody know a way to get the Annotation to read it's values?

EDIT:
Let's look at this implementation:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes( "com.company.api.annotation.CustomAnnotation" )
@SupportedSourceVersion( SourceVersion.RELEASE_8 )  
public class CustomProcessor extends AbstractProcessor
{

  public CustomProcessor()
  {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean process( Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv )
  {
    TypeElement test = annotations.iterator().next();

    for ( Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith( test ) )
    {
      //Here is where I would get the Annotation element itself to 
      //read the content of it if I can use the Annotation as Class Object. 
      SupportedAnnotationTypes generated = elem.getAnnotation( SupportedAnnotationTypes.class );
    }
 }
```

However I don't have to use **CustomAnnotation.class** since it doesn't exist in this environment. How can I do this without owning the Class object?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for ... can't you do Class.forName() first?

Comment: What’s wrong with [`Element.getAnnotationMirrors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getAnnotationMirrors--), followed by [`AnnotationMirror.getElementValues()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/AnnotationMirror.html#getElementValues--)?

Comment: Thanks @Holger that is excactly what I needed!! I didn't find a Question with this problem and didn't know getAnnotationMirrors would be what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the annotations as `AnnotationMirror` which does not require the annotation type to be a loaded runtime `Class`:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    for(TypeElement test: annotations) {
        for( Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith( test ) ) {
            System.out.println(elem);
            for(AnnotationMirror am: elem.getAnnotationMirrors()) {
                if(am.getAnnotationType().asElement()==test)
                    am.getElementValues().forEach((ee,av) ->
                        System.out.println("\t"+ee.getSimpleName()+" = "+av.getValue())
                    );
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hello Holger just got a little question. So I used your comment and have this peace `Map<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> annotationValues = annotationMirrors.get( 0 ).getElementValues();` and this map looks like this: `Key: query(), Value: "from role r where r.deleted = false and r.name = :name"` but when I want to get the value like this: `AnnotationValue annotationValue = annotationValues.get( "query" );` or even using query() in the get, all I get is `null`. Do you know how I can get the value without these for loops?

Comment: The map has `ExecutableElement` as key, so lookups with a `String` can’t work. Since your `process` method receives the annotation type itself as `TypeElement`, you can use `getEnclosedElements()` on it to get the declared annotation members. You may use their names to check which `Element` is the key you need. Once you have it, you can use it repeatedly for looking up the value for each annotated element.